# Series - Finding Limit ln(n)-ln(1+2n)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am taking the limit of the following:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\ln (n)}-{\ln (1+2 n)} = 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (n)}{\ln (1+2 n)}
$$

Doing it one way:
$$
\ln \left(\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{n}{1+2 n}\right) =\ln\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)
$$

And the other way using L'Hôpital's rule:
$$\text{let f(x)} =  \frac{\ln (n)}{\ln (1+2 n)}  $$
$$
\text{L'H} = \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln (x) \frac{d}{d x}}{\ln (1+2 x)\frac{d}{d x}} 
=  \lim _{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \frac{1}{x}}{\frac{2}{1+2x}}= 1$$

So the Series diverge.
But I don't understand why I am getting 2 solutions and which is the correct limit?

Comment: Wait, what? Are you taking the limit of the partial sums of the *series* or taking the limit of the terms?

Comment: The first way is wrong anyway since $\ln(a)/\ln(b)\neq\ln(a/b)$

Comment: @FShrike I am supposed to determine if it is convergent or divergent and if convergent find the sum.

Comment: As you have observed the terms tend towards $1$ so the series cannot converge

Comment: So.  The series is ln(n)-ln(1+2n) =  ln(x/y).  And I think my mistake was turning ln(n)-ln(1+2n) =  ln(n)/ln(1+2n).

Comment: @user41592 Yes: that was your mistake. The correct equality is $$\ln (n)-\ln(1+2n)=\ln(\frac{n}{1+2n}) \to \ln (1/2) \neq 0$$